# How to send the URL-Scheme tel: to a running C# Application?

Tags: c#, tel

I have simple HTML/JS Softphone running in a C# Webview. The App sends a Toast-Notifier if a call comes in and everything is working so far. Even to make it as a standard application for URL-Schemes like "tel:" or "callto:" is working. If i click those links on a webpage my Application starts with the number to call as a argument.

**But there is still one problem:**

The App will be open every time i click that link, no matter it's already running or not. So, it seems to open the App with a shell-command and a argument is not the best solution.

How can i send those URL-Schemes to my App? Maybe my App has to be a Service instead of a simple Application?